# Where can I find UK local authority to county lookup?

Tags: uk

I am using a dataset that has missing counties (UK). I think I can add these to the dataset where the record has a local authority.

I have searched the ONS website and OpenDataCommunities.org, as well as a general web search but have not found a straightforward mapping of local authority to county.

Ideally I'd like a csv file listing UK local authorities and the counties they belong in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Local Authority Service details holds the local council URLS for a number of services where the customer can directly transfer to the appropriate service page on any council in England.
http://local.direct.gov.uk/Data/

The files downloadable are csv.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I used the Local Authority Contact Details file, it had each local authority listed along with most counties.

Comment: Glad that it will help you.